# How to terminate read() when EOF is not encountered?

Tags: c, interrupt, eof

I am building a client/server model but using sockets, using named pipes, with mkfifo().

A client writes output into the name pipe, and I read the input in my server using:

```
while ((n = read(fd_in, &newChar, 1)) == 1) { /* ... */ }
```

I am reading one character at a time, until I encounter the two characters: <'CR'><'LF'>. I would like to make my code in such a way that if a client does not terminate with <'CR'><'LF'> after some time maybe, I can discard it and proceed to another client, otherwise the next client will have to wait, maybe infinitely.

Is there a way please to terminate the execution of read()? If it has not returned in 2 seconds, I could say interrupt read and discard the previously read characters, and start reading again please?

Thank you for your help,

Jary

Comment: Maybe `read` in non-blocking mode and have a timer set for expiration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the `O_NONBLOCK` flag when you `open` the read-end of the FIFO.  That should change the behavior so that `read` returns right away even if the number of requested characters is not in the pipe.

Comment: Thanks that is a nice and really easy solution. I sometime get the error read: Resource temporarily unavailable (because of my while loop) but otherwise it's a great solution, thanks.

Comment: Though busywaiting is something that should preferably be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <poll.h>

do {
    ssize_t ret;
    struct pollfd ps = {.fd = fd_in, .events = POLLIN}; 

    if (poll(&ps, 1, 2000) < 0)
        break; /* kick client */
    ret = read(in_fd, ...);
    if (ret != 1)
        break;
    /* process read data */
} while (true);
```

This checks for whether there is data to be read; if there is not within 2000 msec, do whatever it is you want (e.g. disconnect).

Comment: Thanks your solution works really great. Thanks a lot, it perfectly solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple clients simultaneously, you should set the file descriptors non-blocking with `fcntl()`, and then use `select()` or `poll()` to block until input appears on at least one of them.